# grunt serve works fine but grunt serve:dist giving strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, angular-fullstack

My app works fine with grunt serve but when I test it with grunt serve:dist and try to load modal which I triggered with button click it shows 'templateUrl' which is attached to $mdDialog.show but never shows controller..

here I'm giving files for reference, Ask me if you require any other files as well.

Gruntfile.js

```
    // Generated on 2016-10-17 using generator-angular-material-fullstack 0.1.2
    'use strict';

    module.exports = function (grunt) {
      var localConfig;
      try {
        localConfig = require('./server/config/local.env');
      } catch(e) {
        localConfig = {};
      }

      // Load grunt tasks automatically, when needed
      require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
        express: 'grunt-express-server',
        useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
        ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
        cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
        protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
        buildcontrol: 'grunt-build-control'
      });

      // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
      require('time-grunt')(grunt);

      // Define the configuration for all the tasks
      grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        yeoman: {
          // configurable paths
          client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
          dist: 'dist'
        },
        express: {
          options: {
            port: process.env.PORT || 9000
          },
          dev: {
            options: {
              script: 'server/app.js',
              debug: true
            }
          },
          prod: {
            options: {
              script: 'dist/server/app.js'
            }
          }
        },
        open: {
          server: {
            url: 'http://localhost:'
          }
        },
        watch: {
          injectJS: {
            files: [
              '/{app,components}/**/*.js',
              '!/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
              '!/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
              '!/app/app.js'],
            tasks: ['injector:scripts']
          },
          injectCss: {
            files: [
              '/{app,components}/**/*.css'
            ],
            tasks: ['injector:css']
          },
          mochaTest: {
            files: ['server/**/*.spec.js'],
            tasks: ['env:test', 'mochaTest']
          },
          jsTest: {
            files: [
              '/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
              '/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
            ],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'karma']
          },
          injectSass: {
            files: [
              '/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['injector:sass']
          },
          sass: {
            files: [
              '/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
          },
          gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
          },
          livereload: {
            files: [
              '{.tmp,}/{app,components}/**/*.css',
              '{.tmp,}/{app,components}/**/*.html',

              '{.tmp,}/{app,components}/**/*.js',

              '!{.tmp,}{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
              '!{.tmp,}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
              '/assets/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
              '/assets/icons/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
              '/assets/iconsets/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ],
            options: {
              livereload: true
            }
          },
          express: {
            files: [
              'server/**/*.{js,json}'
            ],
            tasks: ['express:dev', 'wait'],
            options: {
              livereload: true,
              nospawn: true //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
            }
          }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
          options: {
            jshintrc: '/.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
          },
          server: {
            options: {
              jshintrc: 'server/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: [
              'server/**/*.js',
              '!server/**/*.spec.js'
            ]
          },
          serverTest: {
            options: {
              jshintrc: 'server/.jshintrc-spec'
            },
            src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
          },
          all: [
            '/{app,components}/**/*.js',
            '!/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
            '!/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
          ],
          test: {
            src: [
              '/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
              '/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
            ]
          }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              dot: true,
              src: [
                '.tmp',
                '/*',
                '!/.git*',
                '!/.openshift',
                '!/Procfile'
              ]
            }]
          },
          server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
          options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
          },
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '.tmp/',
              src: '{,*/}*.css',
              dest: '.tmp/'
            }]
          }
        },

        // Debugging with node inspector
        'node-inspector': {
          custom: {
            options: {
              'web-host': 'localhost'
            }
          }
        },

        // Use nodemon to run server in debug mode with an initial breakpoint
        nodemon: {
          debug: {
            script: 'server/app.js',
            options: {
              nodeArgs: ['--debug-brk'],
              env: {
                PORT: process.env.PORT || 9000
              },
              callback: function (nodemon) {
                nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
                  console.log(event.colour);
                });

                // opens browser on initial server start
                nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    require('open')('http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858');
                  }, 500);
                });
              }
            }
          }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
          target: {
            src: '/index.html',
            ignorePath: '/',
            exclude: ['/json3/', '/es5-shim/']
          }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
          dist: {
            files: {
              src: [
                '/public/{,*/}*.js',
                '/public/{,*/}*.css',
                '/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                '/public/assets/icons/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                '/public/assets/iconsets/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                '/public/assets/fonts/*'
              ]
            }
          }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
          html: ['/index.html'],
          options: {
            dest: '/public'
          }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
          html: ['/public/{,*/}*.html'],
          css: ['/public/{,*/}*.css'],
          js: ['/public/{,*/}*.js'],
          options: {
            assetsDirs: [
              '/public',
              '/public/assets/images',
              '/public/assets/icons',
              '/public/assets/iconsets'
            ],
            // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
            patterns: {
              js: [
                [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images'],
                [/(assets\/icons\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved icons'],
                [/(assets\/iconsets\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved iconsets']
              ]
            }
          }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '/assets/images',
              src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
              dest: '/public/assets/images'
            }]
          }
        },

        svgmin: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '/assets/images',
              src: '{,*/}*.svg',
              dest: '/public/assets/images'
            }]
          }
        },

        // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
        // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
        ngAnnotate: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '.tmp/concat',
              src: '**/*.js',
              dest: '.tmp/concat'
            }]
          }
        },

        // Package all the html partials into a single javascript payload
        ngtemplates: {
          options: {
            // This should be the name of your apps angular module
            module: 'testfullstackApp',
            htmlmin: {
              collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
              collapseWhitespace: true,
              removeAttributeQuotes: true,
              removeEmptyAttributes: true,
              removeRedundantAttributes: true,
              removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
              removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
            },
            usemin: 'app/app.js'
          },
          main: {
            cwd: '',
            src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
            dest: '.tmp/templates.js'
          },
          tmp: {
            cwd: '.tmp',
            src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
            dest: '.tmp/tmp-templates.js'
          }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
          dist: {
            html: ['/public/*.html']
          }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
          dist: {
            files: [
              {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '',
                dest: '/public',
                src: [
                  '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                  '.htaccess',

                  'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                  'assets/fonts/**/*',
                  'assets/icons/**/*',
                  'assets/iconsets/**/*',
                  'index.html'
                ]
              }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/images',
                dest: '/public/assets/images',
                src: ['generated/*']
              },{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '/bower_components/components-font-awesome/',
                src: ['fonts/*.*'],
                dest: '/public'
              }, {
                expand: true,
                dest: '',
                src: [
                  'package.json',
                  'server/**/*'
                ]
              }]
          },
          styles: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '',
            dest: '.tmp/',
            src: ['{app,components}/**/*.css']
          }
        },

        buildcontrol: {
          options: {
            dir: 'dist',
            commit: true,
            push: true,
            connectCommits: false,
            message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
          },
          heroku: {
            options: {
              remote: 'heroku',
              branch: 'master'
            }
          },
          openshift: {
            options: {
              remote: 'openshift',
              branch: 'master'
            }
          }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
          server: [
            'sass'
          ],
          test: [
            'sass',
          ],
          debug: {
            tasks: [
              'nodemon',
              'node-inspector'
            ],
            options: {
              logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
          },
          dist: [
            'sass',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
          ]
        },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
          unit: {
            configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
          }
        },

        mochaTest: {
          options: {
            reporter: 'spec'
          },
          src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
        },

        protractor: {
          options: {
            configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
          },
          chrome: {
            options: {
              args: {
                browser: 'chrome'
              }
            }
          }
        },

        env: {
          test: {
            NODE_ENV: 'test'
          },
          prod: {
            NODE_ENV: 'production'
          },
          all: localConfig
        },

        // Compiles Sass to CSS
        sass: {
          server: {
            options: {
              loadPath: [
                '/bower_components',
                '/app',
                '/components'
              ],
              compass: false
            },
            files: {
              '.tmp/app/app.css' : '/app/app.scss'
            }
          }
        },

        injector: {
          options: {

          },
          // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
          scripts: {
            options: {
              transform: function(filePath) {
                filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
                filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
                return '';
              },
              starttag: '',
              endtag: ''
            },
            files: {
              '/index.html': [
                [

                  '{.tmp,}/{app,components}/**/*.js',

                  '!{.tmp,}/app/app.js',
                  '!{.tmp,}/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                  '!{.tmp,}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
                ]
              ]
            }
          },

          // Inject component scss into app.scss
          sass: {
            options: {
              transform: function(filePath) {
                filePath = filePath.replace('/client/app/', '');
                filePath = filePath.replace('/client/components/', '');
                return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
              },
              starttag: '// injector',
              endtag: '// endinjector'
            },
            files: {
              '/app/app.scss': [
                '/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}',
                '!/app/app.{scss,sass}'
              ]
            }
          },

          // Inject component css into index.html
          css: {
            options: {
              transform: function(filePath) {
                filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
                filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
                return '';
              },
              starttag: '',
              endtag: ''
            },
            files: {
              '/index.html': [
                '/{app,components}/**/*.css'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      });

      // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
      grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
        grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

        var done = this.async();

        setTimeout(function () {
          grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
          done();
        }, 1500);
      });

      grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function() {
        this.async();
      });

      grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
          return grunt.task.run(['build', 'env:all', 'env:prod', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
        }

        if (target === 'debug') {
          return grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'env:all',
            'injector:sass',
            'concurrent:server',
            'injector',
            'wiredep',
            'autoprefixer',
            'concurrent:debug'
          ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
          'clean:server',
          'env:all',
          'injector:sass',
          'concurrent:server',
          'injector',
          'wiredep',
          'autoprefixer',
          'express:dev',
          'wait',
          'open',
          'watch'
        ]);
      });

      grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve']);
      });

      grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
        if (target === 'server') {
          return grunt.task.run([
            'env:all',
            'env:test',
            'mochaTest'
          ]);
        }

        else if (target === 'client') {
          return grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'env:all',
            'injector:sass',
            'concurrent:test',
            'injector',
            'autoprefixer',
            'karma'
          ]);
        }

        else if (target === 'e2e') {
          return grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'env:all',
            'env:test',
            'injector:sass',
            'concurrent:test',
            'injector',
            'wiredep',
            'autoprefixer',
            'express:dev',
            'protractor'
          ]);
        }

        else grunt.task.run([
            'test:server',
            'test:client'
          ]);
      });

      grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'autoprefixer',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
      ]);

      grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
      ]);
    };
```

the code which triggers the modal show:

```
    $mdDialog.show({
              templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contact/contact.html',
              controller: 'ContactCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'cont',
              locals: {user: vm.currentUser, contact: angular.copy(contact)}
            })
```

again it works fine with grunt serve. So what could be the issue with grunt serve:dist. Any issue in code or configuration of grunt ?

Note:

--it does not give any error on console when modal is opened on grunt serve:dist but any console messages doesn't prints out and no function of controller works..

Comment: The issue is probably because its not able to find the template at that path after the 'build' process. Try using `template` instead of `templateUrl`. Does that work?

Comment: It shows up the modal.. so it is able to find the templateUrl.. but it is not binding the controller with it. That is my question..